# Can we edit scale of 3D object in world space programmatically in SceneKit?

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, scenekit, arkit

I am working with ARKit in iOS and I want to reduce the size of actual object in real world. With pinch gesture we can resize object but When I tap, I want to place object with reduced size.
In SceneKit Editor, if we select editing space to world then scaling option is not available. So is it possible to edit scale of 3D object in world space programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

I did this about 1.5 year ago. I can't promise it still works. But first you add your listeners:

```
let pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(adjustWindow))
    let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(adjustWindow))
    let rotateGesture = UIRotationGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(adjustWindow))
    let tapGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(adjustWindow))
    pinchGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    rotateGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    panGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    tapGesture.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2
    sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
    sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)
    sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(rotateGesture)
    sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

And then some to handle the action:

```
@objc func adjustWindow(_ gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        // Fetch location for touch in sceneView
        let location: CGPoint = gesture.location(in: sceneView)
        // Fetch targets at the current location
        let hits = self.sceneView.hitTest(location, options: nil)
        // Check if it's a node and it's a window node that has been touched
        guard let node = hits.first?.node, node.name == "window" else {return}

        // Rotate the window if the motion is of the rotation kind
        if let rotateRecognizer = gesture as? UIRotationGestureRecognizer {
            let action = SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0, y: rotateRecognizer.rotation/200 , z: 0, duration: 0.1)
            node.runAction(action)
            return
        }

        // Make sure user is using 1 finger to move the view
        if gesture.numberOfTouches == 1 {
            switch gesture.state {
            case .failed, .cancelled, .ended:
                startPosition = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
                break
            case .began:
                // Save start position, so that we can check how far the user have moved
                startPosition = location
            case .changed:
                // Fetch new x and y position

                // Note that 1 point is 1 meter and since we want minimal movement we divide it greatly
                let deltaX = Float(location.x-startPosition.x)/400
                let deltaY = Float(location.y-startPosition.y)/20000
                // Transform and apply the new location

                // You can either move the axises of the nodes parents by using "node.scale = SCNVector(x,y,z)"
                // Or you can move the axises of the node itself by transforming the nodes reality as below
                // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43237805/how-to-move-a-rotated-scnnode-in-scenekit
                let box = node.transform
                let translation = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(-deltaX, deltaY, 1)
                let newTrans = SCNMatrix4Mult(translation, box)
                node.transform = newTrans

                node.localTranslate(by: SCNVector3Make(-deltaX, deltaY, 1))
                // Set new location
                startPosition = location
            default:
                break
            }
            // Make sure user is using 2 fingers for scaling the view
        } else if gesture.numberOfTouches == 2, let pinchGesture = gesture as? UIPinchGestureRecognizer {
            switch pinchGesture.state {
            case .began:
                // Save start position, so that we can check how far the user have moved
                startPosition = location
            case .changed:

                // MARK: - Scaling
                // Scaling is unaffected as long as it scales with it's own current value hence we fetch
                // node.scale locations where we want it to be unaffected

                // Scale vertically if user moved more than 4 points

                // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44850927/scaling-a-scnnode-in-runtime-using-the-pan-gesture
                if abs(location.y-startPosition.y) > 4 {
                    let pinchScaleY: CGFloat = pinchGesture.scale * CGFloat((node.scale.y))
                    node.scale = SCNVector3Make(node.scale.x, Float(pinchScaleY), node.scale.z)
                // Else scale horizontally, if the user moved more than 4 points horizontally
                } else if abs(location.x-startPosition.x) > 4 {
                    let pinchScaleX: CGFloat = pinchGesture.scale * CGFloat((node.scale.x))
                    node.scale = SCNVector3Make(Float(pinchScaleX), node.scale.y, node.scale.z)
                }
                pinchGesture.scale = 1
            default:
                break
            }
        } else if let panGesture = gesture as? UIPanGestureRecognizer, panGesture.numberOfTouches == 2 {
            switch panGesture.state {
            case .failed, .cancelled, .ended:
                startPosition = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
                break
            case .began:
                // Save start position, so that we can check how far the user have moved
                startPosition = location
            case .changed:
                // Fetch new x and y position
                let deltaZ = Float(location.y-startPosition.y)/2000
                // Set new position
                node.position = SCNVector3Make(node.position.x, node.position.y, node.position.z+deltaZ)
                // Set new location
                startPosition = location
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

I know that this contains code for moving the node and rotating it and everything. But the pinching part is in the middle:
`else if gesture.numberOfTouches == 2, let pinchGesture = gesture as? UIPinchGestureRecognizer`

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible- you can adjust the scale of nodes by using the node's `scale` parameter (`node.scale`).